# Compiler errors on for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, compiler-errors

Here are the errors:

```
main.c|188|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token|
main.c|195|error: expected expression before '}' token|
main.c|195|error: expected expression before '}' token|
main.c|195|error: expected expression before '}' token|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

And here's the part of my code where they appear, along with the corresponding line numbers:
(I am compiling this on Codeblocks)

```
//If Option 4 is selected

if (input == 4) {
    printf("You selected Option 4: Display all courses.\n");
    for (int counter = 0, counter < 560000, counter++) { //line 188
        course ToDisplay;
        fread(&ToDisplay, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);
        if (ToDisplay.dept != 000 && ToDisplay.num != 000) {
            printf("%2s.%d.%d %d.%d ", ToDisplay.div, ToDisplay.dept, ToDisplay.num, ToDisplay.credits, ToDisplay.title);`
        }
    }
} //line 195
```

Comment: Seriously? `,` in `for` loop instead of `;`?

Comment: Wow, yeah - don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use semicolons instead of commas in statement

```
for (int counter = 0, counter < 560000, counter++) { //line 188
                    ^^                ^^
```

Othrewise the compiler consideres record

```
int counter = 0, counter < 560000, counter++
```

as a declaration of several variables (with the same name)